# Does $S^{\perp\perp}=\overline{S}$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I'm trying to prove that $S^{\perp\perp} = \overline{S}$, where S is a subspace of a Hilbert Space, where $S^{\perp\perp} = \{f: \langle f,g\rangle = 0, \forall g\in S^\perp\}$ and $\overline{S}$ is the closure under limits of sequences. I can easily show that $f\in \overline{S} \implies f \in S^{\perp\perp}$ but I don't know how to prove the converse. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: you probably meant a inner product space, note that a Hilbert space is complete, and hence if $S$ is a subspace then $S = \overline{S}$.

Comment: @user1952009 No, subspaces of Hilbert spaces do not need to be complete. For example $C[0,1]$ is a non-complete subspace of $L^2[0,1]$. This question is posed correctly.

Comment: @Ian : ok but you didn't convince me, under what definition is $C[0,1]$ a subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ ? whatever it is not so important

Comment: @user1952009 Every element of $C[0,1]$ is an element of $L^2[0,1]$; sums of elements of $C[0,1]$ are elements of $C[0,1]$; scalar multiples of elements of $C[0,1]$ are elements of $C[0,1]$. One might pedantically disagree with my first statement through something about equivalence classes but it is not really important.

Comment: @user1952009 $C[0,1]$ is a subspace means that $C[0,1]$ is a *vector subspace*; we need not allow infinite sums in the definition of a subspace and generally do not.

Comment: yes sorry it's the different between a subspace and a closed subspace, whatever, $S^{\perp}$ is complete ? we agree on that ?

Comment: @user1952009 yes.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043940/double-orthogonal-complement-is-equal-to-topological-closure

Comment: You know that $S\subset \overline{S}$ and hence $S^{\perp\perp}\subset \overline{S}^{\perp\perp}$; if you know that $S^{\perp\perp} = S$ for $S$ closed then you have the reverse inclusion that you need... Not sure if that helps though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so here is the summary.

One should first note the following easy properties:

1. $S \subseteq S^{\perp \perp}$
2. $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \implies S_2^{\perp} \subseteq S_1^{\perp}$
3. For a closed subspace $M$ the orthogonal projection theorem gives that $M^{\perp \perp} = M$.
4. $S^{\perp}$ is a closed subset for every $S$.

Then one proceeds as follows.

$\Rightarrow)$ Always $S \subseteq \overline{S}$ and by 2. $S^{\perp \perp} \subseteq \overline{S}^{\perp \perp}$ but since $\overline{S}$ is a closed subset 3. gives that $\overline{S}^{\perp \perp} = \overline{S}$. This gives the desired inclusion.

$\Leftarrow)$ Since by 4. $S^{\perp \perp}$ is closed and by 1. $S \subseteq S^{\perp \perp}$ by the monotonicity of topological closure we have that $\overline{S} \subseteq \overline{S^{\perp \perp}} = S^{\perp \perp}$.  This gives the opposite inclusion.

Comment: You should have $$\overline {S} \subseteq \overline {\left (S^{\perp}\right )^{\perp}} =  \left (S^{\perp}\right )^{\perp}$$ at the very last line. Right?

Comment: Nice!  (To remove distractions for anyone referencing this answer in the future, I corrected the typo in the original answer that prompted the two comments before this one.)