# Prove or disprove $closure$ of $span S$= Perp of S perp

Tags: inner-products

My attempt:
I am trying to disprove it by geometry. In R2 take X axis and it a subspace of R2(call it M). Now M perp will be all straight line perpendicular to X axis , and perp of M perp will be all straight line parallel to X axis(note that X asix also include). Now span (M)=M as M is a subspace. Closure of span(M) is M ( since subspace are closed) that means X axis.
So conclusion as X axis can not equal all straight line parallel to X axis,. So relation is not true.

My question what wrong i have done?

Comment: Mind that closure of S is with respect to the topology induced by inner product

Answer (score 1):

So, this is actually correct. For any subset $S$ of an inner product space $V$, we do have
$$\operatorname{\overline{span}} S = (S^\perp)^\perp.$$
In terms of where you went wrong with your example, I think you have an issue with your understanding about the perpendicular complement. We define
$$S^\perp = \{v \in V : \langle v, w \rangle = 0\}.$$
In particular, if $S$ is the $x$-axis, i.e. $S = \{(x, 0) : x \in \Bbb{R}\}$, then $(a, b) \in S^\perp$ if and only if
$$(a, b) \cdot (x, 0) = 0$$
for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. In particular, if we consider $x = 1$, we require
$$0 = (a, b) \cdot (1, 0) = a,$$
i.e. $(a, b)$ takes the form $(0, b)$. That is, $(a, b)$ lies on the $y$-axis.

In particular, note that this is **not** the set of lines parallel to the $y$-axis, it is just the $y$-axis itself. Remember, a $0$ inner product means that the vectors are perpendicular from the origin.

Similarly, of course, $(S^\perp)^\perp$ is the $x$-axis. It's just a collection of vectors which are perpendicular to the $y$-axis, **starting at the origin**.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you prove the statement? Please.

Comment: I could, but I think that'd be a separate question. Moreover, the question would likely be a duplicate (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043940/double-orthogonal-complement-is-equal-to-topological-closure/1043988#1043988), or dig through [these search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5E%5Cperp%29%5E%5Cperp+closure+span)).

Comment: Actually i have tried to prove that. But i am not satisfied with my proof

Comment: Perfect! What you should do then is create a new question, write your proof in the question, tag the question [tag:proof-verification] or [tag:solution-verification], and ask how you can fix the proof if it's not valid. Ping me a message here, and I'll be happy to look at it (although, I'm sure someone will answer it relatively quickly). I'm off to bed now. :-)

Comment: How to ping you? I have posted my solution.